# Endeca - Dimension product.category does not exist

Tags: search, atg, endeca, oracle-commerce

In Endeca Dgraph (MDEX), the following error is logged repeatedly. 
This affects cache components of ATG.

```
DGRAPH  {dgraph}        Dimension product.category does not exist
```

The cacheMap of `DimensionValueCacheTools` component is not getting populated with category dimension but only with emptyCacheMap. refreshCache is also not providing the expected results.

Seeing the following error, which is actually logged from `DimensionValueCacheRefreshHandler`

```
**** Error      Tue Sep 12 12:37:38 -04:00 2017 1505234258871   /atg/endeca/assembler/AssemblerTools    No dimension whose name matches product.category could be found.
```

Please provide your valuable thoughts.

Comment: What are the values in the CategoryRootNodeSynchronization.properties and the SchemaExporter.properties? Perhaps you have an unmapped Dimension for product.category.

Comment: CategoryRootNodeSynchronization -> dimensionName=product.category  SchemaExporter -> propertyNameToDimensionName={product.parentCategory.id=product.category}

Comment: have the above properties in the components and also in Schema record XML has the following inc..                                         
<RECORD><PROP NAME="attribute.name"><PVAL>product.category</PVAL></PROP><PROP NAME="attribute.source_name"><PVAL>product.parentCategory.id</PVAL></PROP><PROP NAME="attribute.type"><PVAL>dimension</PVAL></PROP><PROP NAME="attribute.search.searchable"><PVAL>true</PVAL></PROP>    <PROP NAME="attribute.search.wildcard"><PVAL>true</PVAL></PROP></RECORD>

Comment: Seems like product.category is not indexed in Endeca or all products belongs to same category. Can you please check if Catalog Maintenance Service has been run before indexing?

Comment: CMS was executed without any errors but still we have issue in MDEX. But In Jspref, we do get the 'product.category' though.

Comment: you might be referencing the wrong dimension id for product.category in Cache component of ATG.

Comment: Edited the question to provide more details.

Comment: as part of /atg/endeca/assembler/cartridge/handler/config/DimensionValueCacheRefreshConfig/ this component, you need to define the Dimension ID for which you need to define cache in dimensionList /?propertyName=dimensionList. This Id is endeca Ne value and please check if this value is product.category Ne value or not.

Comment: DimensionValueCacheRefreshConfig -> dimensionList was null. Changed to product.category. the enabled flag is true. Should perform anyother change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154363/discussion-between-muralidharan-rade-and-ajay-agrawal).

Answer (score 0):

In the following ATG component

```
/atg/endeca/assembler/cartridge/handler/config/DimensionValueCacheRefreshConfig
```

**dimensionList** property should not be null.

dimensionList property should be updated with the Dimension ID of the product.category.

This value can be obtained from Endeca.

Answer (score 0):

During the baseline update process the product.category data was not output.  Try running the CMS component and re-baselining.

Check there are no errors in the PCOC file ProductCatalogOutputConfig. You can use the dyn/admin components responsible for baselining to also debug.

You will need the JSPref app in the workbench to reflect the product.category dimension before you will see anything in this cache.